# Cordova error when using angular to get remote json

Tags: json, cordova

I develop a little mobile app with cordova + onsen ui platform, i develop on a macbook pro, all things works perfectly but when i try to get remote json i get following error :

```
Uncaught Error: Module     org.apache.cordova.file.resolveLocalFileSystemURI does not exist.
```

I search on google but not found similar issue, anyone can help me please?

Thank you.

Below is latest detail :
I deleted all angular json call and "Uncaught Error: Module org.apache.cordova.file.requestFileSystem does not exist." remain, so i think it's not an angular problem but cordova issue

---

Thanks all for your question, this is my code to get json from angular :

Note : i use onsen UI framework for the UI

```
ons.ready(function(){

    myapp.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://www.e-sysoft.fr/myicc/?get=events').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.posts = data;
            alert(data)
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // log error
        });
    });

})
```

When i run this code nothing happens could you help me?

Comment: may be you miss file plugin installation

Comment: may be your are entering URL in undefined format. Check your URL.

Comment: @happenask what do you mean with file plugin installation?

Comment: @mkysoft i checked url but error remain, thanks for your help

Comment: Can you post your code that's making Ajax call to get the remote JSON?

Comment: @user44321 I mean you should install file plugin like this `$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file`
`$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer`